# CSS padding effecting width & height of component

Tags: css, padding, fixed-width

How can I give fixed width & height of button or label even after applying the big padding.

I tried with `box-sizing:content-box`. but its not working.

[Example code](http://jsfiddle.net/jWbVA/2/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you looking for `box-sizing: border-box` instead?

I think you are.

Comment: I tried border-box also, still it is increasing width of label & button. I want the button & label size should be same as initial(without padding) even after applying padding but content should go invisible if I apply big padding.